# How to prevent the Garbage Collector to slow down my application

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Let's say I've got an applciation which has a memory leak. At some point the GC will try very hard to clear memory and will slow down my application. I know that if you set this parameter for the JVM -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit it will throw an OutOfMemoryException:

> if more than 98% of the total time is spent in garbage collection and less than 2% of the heap is recovered.

However this is somehow not good enough for me. Because my application will become very slow even before these numbers hit. The GC will absorb the CPU for some time before the OutOfMemoryException will be thrown. My goal is to somehow recognize very early if there will most likly a problem and then throw the OutOfMemoryexception. After that I have some kind of recovery strategy.

Ok now I've found these two additional parameters GCTimeLimit and GCHeapFreeLimit. With them it is possible to tweak the two quoted constants (98% and 2%).

I've made some tests on my own like a small piece of code which produces a memory leak and played with those settings. But I'm not really sure how to find the correct tradeoff. My hope is that someone else had the same problem and came up with a reasonable solution, or maybe there are some other GC switches which i don't know yet.

I'm feeling a little bit lost since I'm not really an expert on this topic and it seems that there are a lot of thing's which can be considered.

Comment: Instead of trying to defeat the garbage collector, perhaps you should patch the memory leak?

Comment: Doesn't it seem more reasonable to fix the memory leak? This seems like a drip pan under the memory leak.

Comment: Which JVM? What version? GC tuning parameters/methods are proprietary to each JVM implementation.

Comment: It sounds like @kukudas is presenting a thought experiment for him/herself rather than a real problem, so I am going to humor him with some serious answers.

Comment: Well you guy's are right. If there is a memory leak it should be fixed. But it can always happen that somehow, me or some other developer introduces a new bug which results into a memory leak. So my goal is that the application should be more stable in a scenario where a memory leak appears which was not known yet. Of course if it appear we will fix it.

Comment: @Ryan most likly it will be Oracle JVM (latest 6). What gave you the impression to conclude it is not a real problem?

Comment: @kukudas just your wording: "let's say I have a..."

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Sun/Oracle JVM, [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html) page seems to be a pretty complete GC-tuning primer.

Comment: @Крысa Because they are two very different answers providing multiple choices for solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [java.lang.management.MemoryUsage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryUsage.html) to determine the used memory, and total memory available. As it approaches the tunable GC collection threshold then you can throw your error.

Of course doing this is a little ridiculous. If the issue is that you need more memory then increase the heap size. The more likely issue is that you're not releasing memory gracefully when you're done with it.

Comment: I thought about an similar solution. But the problem is that it is really hard to tell if the behavior is just a heavy load situation or some kind of memory leak. It is not problem if the application needs a lot of memory as long as it releases enough again. The problem arises if from each collection something is left over.

Comment: From the sound of it the garbage collector is thrashing because there are not enough unreferenced objects to release. If it happens after running for a while, rather than in response to a specific set of conditions that's a fairly classic symptom of a java memory leak. You should inspect your heap - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145922/how-can-i-see-what-is-in-my-heap-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Side-step the JVM heap and use something like [Terra Cotta's Big Memory](http://terracotta.org/bigmemory-ulloa-release) which uses direct memory management to grow beyond the reach of the garbage collector.