# Java - Count class instances runtime

Tags: java, out-of-memory, memory-leak-detector

I want to know if exist any tool or eclipse plugin for java that list the count of instances per class at **runtime**.
I need it to test a memory leak issue.
Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145922/how-can-i-see-what-is-in-my-heap-in-java?rq=1

Comment: Can i create the head dump also without OOM?

Comment: If you have a small amount of places where you instantiate this class why not just put a counter variable there to count every time you make and instance and dump it out to console or a text file? It's not pretty or the most efficient way to go about it but its and easy to implement solution

Comment: I tried, but with hundred of threads it's difficult to keep trace of each variable.

Comment: I'm usually using jvisualvm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the best eclipse plugin to find memory leaks is [Memory Analyzer (MAT)](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)