# how to apply MaxHeapFreeRatio on my web application

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

i making a web program, and its consume more and more memory from time to time.
after searching from google i think i have found the solution.

i use system.gc() for garbage collection, and quite do the work.
but its still consume a lot of resource. so i back to google and found about profiling (i use netbean ).
after profiling my project i have found that allocated heap for my app is 500 mb, while actually it only use under 200 mb. 
[this is before system.gc() after that less then 100 mb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0l8DJ.png)

then here [Is there a way to lower Java heap when not in use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952568/is-there-a-way-to-lower-java-heap-when-not-in-use) it tell me that i can encourage jvm to lower the heap..

any one know how to configure -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio step to step? cause im still newbie. iam using win 7 right now

if this help, i found that surviving generation keep increasing too [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tswG7.png)

thank you

Comment: how about identifying what is using your heap.

Comment: could you tell me how to do that?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145922/how-can-i-see-what-is-in-my-heap-in-java

Comment: i tipe this on my cmd   "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin>jmap -dump:format=b,file=heap.bin <pid>" but it say command is incorrect sir

Comment: did i do it wrong?